# sqoop incremental import to hive table

Tags: hive, sqoop, oozie

I am trying to do a sqoop incremental import (lastmodified) to a hive table . It is working in sqoop 1.4.5 but not in sqoop 1.4.6 .

It is throwing the following error

**Log Upload Time: Mon Nov 13 17:57:58 +0530 2017

```
        Log Length: 246
      --incremental lastmodified option for hive imports is not supported. Please remove the parameter --incremental lastmodified.
```

Intercepting System.exit(1)
Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain], exit code [1]**

Comment: Thank you very much sqoop committers for breaking our legacy jobs, facing the same issues today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sqoop 1.4.6 doesn't support incremental import to a hive table directly.

However you can import the incremental data without using the `--hive-import` option and place the incremental data in the HDFS location which is mapped to the hive table using the `--target-dir` option.

For example

Consider there's a table `sqoop_pract` with location set to `/user/hive/warehouse/sqoop_pract`

If you want to perform incremental import for this table you can use a query similar to the following

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://hostname/sample_db --username demo --table sqoop_pract --target-dir /user/hive/warehouse/sqoop_pract --incremental lastmodified --check-column Ts --last-value '2017-11-08 03:51:42' --append -P
```

In the above command the `--target-dir` points to the hive table's location, this way you can achieve incremental import to a hive table using sqoop.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation and is there any reason you are aware of on why hive import option was removed in 1.4.6 version.

Comment: No I'm not aware of it

Comment: In the table I am importing from , there are certain newline characters in the data . Is there any work around for --hive-drop-delims .

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop (versions 1.4.6 or below) import is able to run with `--hive-import` and `--incremental lastmodified` options but it produces unexpected results. 
See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-2986

Answer (score 0):

you can choose hcatalog instead of hive.

Comment: Thank you for your response . Can you please elaborate you answer.